# Rotate a 3d image

Tags: html, css

On the website that I'm working on, there is an image that is initially rotated. I'm asked to turn it back so that it is facing us properly, but I really have no idea how to do it, I've tried

```
transform: rotateY(10deg);

transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 45deg);
```

but they don't seem to be working.

I've created a minimal reproducible example here -

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  transform:rotateY(140deg)
/*  need to turn it so that the picture is facing us with its front side  */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/pw8Mc2M/product-redox.png" alt="product-redox" border="0">
</div>
```

if someone could help with turning this image, I'd be really glad.

This is how it should look:

[image: image screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code or a screenshot of how it should look instead.

Comment: @Progman added a screenshot, thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: You have a two dimensional `png` image with a 3D model in it. I don't think that it's possible to get the look you want just by using CSS. And that's because all transformations will take place in the image and not the image's model.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by cutting the image using `clip-path` to keep only the needed side, then apply a transformation:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  filter:drop-shadow(-15px 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  clip-path:polygon(0% 4%,73.6% 16.5%,73.6% 100%,0 100%);
  transform:skew(-8deg) rotate(-7deg) rotateY(-7deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/pw8Mc2M/product-redox.png" alt="product-redox" border="0">
</div>
```